# Password protected keys in AndroidKeystore

Tags: android, keystore

I have Generated a RSA key pair in AndroidKeystore. I need to protect my Alias with a password so that no other can access the same alias without the password.
I have used the following code to generate the keypair.

```
if (!keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {

    Calendar notBefore = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar notAfter = Calendar.getInstance();
    notAfter.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(this)
        .setAlias(alias)
        .setKeyType("RSA")
        .setKeySize(2048)
        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=test"))
        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
        .setStartDate(notBefore.getTime())
        .setEndDate(notAfter.getTime())
        .build();
    KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
    generator.initialize(spec);

    KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
}
```

Comment: I guess your previous question is basically the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748436/how-to-set-key-entry-with-password-in-android-keystore It is a good practice to edit the question to include more information if you want an accurate answer

Comment: Yes, at that time I have no code even for create the keypair. now I got it but I don't know how set password.

Comment: I answered there. Note that `KeyPairGeneratorSpec` is deprecated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420586/how-to-safely-save-alias-key-of-android-keystore/49431434#49431434